# multiple database connection in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Issue with multiple database connections in **Django** and assigning to a model

As I need to create modules( which will only read records from the database) from different source(MSSQL, ORACLE, CMS)I am trying to configure Database details in `setting.py`.

For the setting of my MSSQL database, the connection was not happening when I look at the connection string that was created by Django `base.py` file
it is

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}; Server=<servername>, 
<portnumber>; Trusted_Connection=yes;  Database=<databasename; 
user=<username>; Passoword=<password>
```

But actually the connection string will work only when the `Trusted_Connection=yes` comes after the database details like below

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}; Server=<servername>, 
<portnumber>; Database=<databasename; Trusted_Connection=yes; 
user=<username>; Passoword=<password>
```

Is there any thing I am doing wrong in my DATABASE details. 
below is my database detail.

```
'MDMDB': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'DATABSENAME',
        'USER': '<username',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': 'HOSTNAME:PORTNAME',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
        'Trusted_Connection':'yes',
}
```

Comment: Note: 'Trusted_Connection':'yes', can be removed from the configuration details and can be used only when we use the windows credentials (where we dont have to pass the username and password).

Comment: Got it working by modifying the pyodbc\base.py file :
in pyodbc\base.py commented  the line below line where we add the port name with the server name 
#host = ','.join((host, str(port)))
and added  
cstr_parts['PORT'] = str(port). 
This will create the connection string as Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}; Server=<servername>; PORT =<PORT NUMBER>; Database=<databasename; UID=<username>; PWD=<password>